# Как создать обработчик вложеных URL в urls.py

Tags: url, python, регулярные-выражения, django

Пишу сайт на джанго.Опыта в веб-разработке конечно маловато...

Но таки

Содержание urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'catalog/', section),
)
```

При обращении к catalog/ выводится список категорий в каталоге товаров.Идет обработка.Создается хтмл-страница ис шаблона,в ней генерится новый адрес для перехода.В итоге мы имеем н-цать ссылок на странице вида catalog/ссылка1,catalog/ссылка2....catalog/ссылка-Н(названия все разные и длины адресов тоже).Что ставить в обработчик урлов дабы обрабатывало по маске catalog/mask/

Comment: Непроходит(((


urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'catalog/(?P<catalog_slug>\w+)/',subsection),
(r'catalog/', section),
)


Я хочу обработать функцией subsection(выводит список подкатегорий).А он все гребет section(выводит список категорий).Может проблема в русских буквах в адресе?

Извиняюсь за оформление коммента.Фиг его знает как оформить содержание как вставку кода.

Answer (score 2):

```
(r'catalog/(?P<catalog_slug>\w+)/$', section),
```

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 1):

Решено :)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^catalog/(?P<sub>\w+)/$',subsection),
(r'^catalog/$', section),
)
```